# Scaling the Axis of a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

So I've been fighting with LaTeX for a while now and haven't really gotten a conclusive answer on how to deal with this issue.

[image]

I have a plot and this is how my axis looks like. I obviously want to make it evenly spaced between each number.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,
    height = \axisdefaultheight,
    title={Bubble Sort and Insertion Sort Algorithm Performance},
    xlabel={Number of Elements[in thousand]},
    ylabel={Time [in minutes]},
           xmin=5, xmax = 500,
           ymin = 0, ymax = 30,
    xtick = {5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500},
    ytick = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30},
    legend pos = north west,
    grid style = dashed
]
```

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish that? Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem. I guess you want each data point to be evenly spaced but the corresponding labels should be not evenly spaced, right? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Same principle as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377011/ I guess, i.e. plot the data at regularly spaced x-values (1,2,3,...), and specify the `xticklabels` separately. Details might depend on exactly how you input the data.